# How to limit nodes to open in an Access-2010 Treeview

Tags: ms-access, vba, treeview, ms-access-2010

I have built a Treeview in Access-2010 with over 70.000 nodes (Access-VBA). To open it takes a lot of time. After that, it works fine. I've looked on several sides for VBA-code to make this work faster. There is apparently a way to do so which is called "delayed loading" (don’t load the child nodes until the parent node is expanded). Can anybody help to this VBA-code?

Comment: .... and where is your vba code? :)

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with the treeview control, but I would suspect you'd dynamically add the child nodes at the point when a parent node is expanded rather than all at once.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Krish, the VBA-code I used for the treeview is not a secret, it comes literal from the instruction videos (youtube) from the SmileyCoder. Matt, the solution you gave is correct. I'm looking for an example in VBA-code.